# unable to get-item for local dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I am following [this article](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/getting-started-step-3.html) to read data from a local dynamodb running in a docker container. I was able to add data to it and I can also see the data has been added using a scan operation. However, when I run this command below copied straight out from the documentation I get an error.

**CLI Command**

```
aws dynamodb get-item --consistent-read  --table-name Music --key '{ "Artist": {"S": "Acme Band"}, "SongTitle": {"S": "Happy Day"}}' --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

**Error**

> usage: aws [options]   [ ...]
>   [parameters] To see help text, you can run:
>
> aws help   aws  help   aws   help
>
> Unknown options: {S:, Acme Band},, SongTitle:, {S:, Happy Day}}',
>   Artist:

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Sounds like you're on Windows?  [This may help](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-quoting-strings.html).

Comment: yep that was it!!. .Thanks :)